# Renyi's proof of Faddeev's theorem: convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can we prove that$$
\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{m} \frac{\delta_{k}}{m}=0$$
given $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty}\delta_{k}=0$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon$ be given.  $\exists M (m>M\implies |\delta_n|<\varepsilon)$.  Choose $m$ so large that $$m>M \text{ and } \frac{1}{m} \left\lvert\sum_{k=0}^M{\delta_k}\right\rvert<\varepsilon$$  Then
$$\frac{1}{m}\left\lvert\sum_{k=0}^m{\delta_k}\right\rvert\le
\frac{1}{m} \left\lvert\sum_{k=0}^M{\delta_k}\right\rvert+\frac{1}{m} \left\lvert\sum_{k=M+1}^m{\delta_k}\right\rvert\le\frac{M\varepsilon}{m}+\varepsilon<2\varepsilon
$$

Comment: Thanks , i wasn't paying attention to the question, it turns out that this is an application of Césaro's theorem